# OpenGL FrameBuffer in Qt fails to initialize

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, framebuffer

I'm porting an application of mine from Glut to Qt. However, I cannot port my FrameBuffer. The following code works in my Glut application, but not in my Qt port.

```
// delete handles
glDeleteFramebuffersEXT(1, fboId);
glDeleteTextures(1, colorTexture);
glDeleteTextures(1, depthTexture);

// color texture
glGenTextures(1, colorTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *colorTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F_ARB, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);    
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

// depth texture
glGenTextures(1, depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, *depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width, height, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

// rebuild FBO
glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, fboId);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, *fboId);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, *colorTexture, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, *depthTexture, 0);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    printf("Error while creating framebuffer\n");
    exit(1);
}

OpenGL::detectError(); // checks glGetError()

// disconnect FBO
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

In my Qt port I get the error that the FrameBuffer object is not complete. Is there some additional setup required that I'm missing? The OpenGL code in Qt is wrapped in an QGLWidget.

Comment: which version of Qt do you use?

Comment: Why are you mix-n-matching EXT (`glFramebufferTexture2DEXT()`) and core (`glCheckFramebufferStatus()`) FBO entry-points/enums?

Comment: Qt 4.8.5, but I already found out the issue lies somewhere else and this code does work. Debugging OpenGL is no fun, but this question can be closed.